There are no sufficient IP addresses in the VPC network. Cloud Run Deployment using Terraform and direct VPC
I was using Cloud Serverless VPC access to enable connection to a private db all fine. But it had some unwanted costs so I switched to Direct VPC.
However, since, I get an error when I try to apply Terraform :
 Error: Error code 13, message: Revision 'deployed-run-00032-bmj' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. Health check failed for the deployment with the user-provided VPC network. There are no sufficient IP addresses in the VPC network.

Here is my subnet config :
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "custom_test" {
  name          = "vpc-con"
  project = data.google_project.project.project_id
  ip_cidr_range = "10.2.0.0/20"
  region        = "us-central1"
  network       = google_compute_network.private_network.name
  private_ip_google_access = true

}

Here is my Cloud Run config :
resource "google_cloud_run_v2_service" "file_ingestor" {

  project = data.google_project.project.project_id
  name     = "cloudrun"
  location = "us-central1"

  template {
    max_instance_request_concurrency = 2
    containers {
      image = "us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/hello"
      resources {
          limits = {
          cpu    = "4"
          memory = "2048Mi"
        }
      }

    service_account = google_service_account.eventarc.email

    vpc_access {
      network_interfaces {
        network    = google_compute_network.private_network.name
        subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.custom_test.name
        #tags       = ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
      }
    }

  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      client,
      client_version,
      labels["commit-sha"],
      labels["managed-by"],
      template[0].labels["commit-sha"],
      template[0].labels["managed-by"],
      template[0].containers[0].image,
    ]
  }
}

I chose the /20 mask especially to have enough IPs.
What is also strange is that I cannot find the version name in the error in the console, I see another version name that is SUCCESSFULLY deployed. When repeating the operation, I receive updateService events in console but that's it, all is running fine BUT Terraform fails with the following:
 Error: Error code 13, message: Revision 'deployed-run-00032-bmj' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. Health check failed for the deployment with the user-provided VPC network. There are no sufficient IP addresses in the VPC network.

Does someone understand what is going on?
How to make terraform ignore deployment status? (because I can't run terraform anymore and I think that it's not its role to check that.)

On a side note, how to format Terraform on stackoverflow ```terraform does not seem to work.

I think that your  user-provided VPC  IP range is overlaping with the default one,double check this.

I just had to wait a bit. It is working now.
In the doc, they talk about waiting but I don't know whether it is the same context.

To delete the subnet, you must first delete or redeploy your Cloud Run services or jobs to stop using the subnet, and then wait 1-2 hours.

